# Optimizing location updates storage

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, bigdata

I receive location updates from drivers and store them in a table having the following attributes and structure :

```
id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
driverId int NOT NULL,
updateTime datetime2(2) NOT NULL,
latitude decimal(9,6) NOT NULL,
Longitude decimal(9,6) NOT NULL,
isAvailabe bit NOT NULL,
isBusy bit NOT NULL
```

Currently the table contains more than 70M rows and keeps growing (500K rows per day). I frequently delete part of the table to free up the disk and make the data processing a bit faster but it is not a wise solution.

Is there any way to optimize the storage of the location updates?

Comment: Please explain why you have tags for both "hadoop" and "sql-server".

Comment: Your question mentions updates in the title but it seems this table might only be maintained via updates and deletes.  Is your "processing" of the table queries that require full scans?  Exactly what do you mean by "optimizing storage"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff to see if hadoop can be considered as a solution for this situation or still early to consider it.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes, the processing does requires a full scan of the table. I want to know if there are other ways to store the location updates (instead of storing them in a sql table)

Comment: @Saadb, there are many possible solutions. The optimal way to store this data depends much on how it is used so you need to add that to your question.  Even then, the question may be too broad.  If "processing" means getting the current location of each available driver in real time, that could be done in SQL with proper indexing without a full scan.

Comment: @DanGuzman  an example of processing would be to know how many drivers are in certain location in a certain period of time; or at a single period of time how many drivers are connected in the network and nearby a certain location

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do geospatial operations but aren't using the native geospatial capabilities of SQL Server. Before running deletes on what frankly appears to be a tiny data set in the service of optimizing queries against it, I'd look into using the geography data type to make your queries faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow your question 100%.  But I do get the gist about deleting large numbers of records.

The best solution for that is to partition your table, so different rows are in different partitions.  You can then just drop a partition, which is much faster than deleting the rows.

Read about partitioning in SQL Server [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx).